# Bootstrap modal - Add a object tag embedding a PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to display a bootstrap modal in which I want to include a PDF file with the "object" html tag. Problem is that nothing seems to display.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/3/) (http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/3/).

So you will find a basic modal (exactly same code from bootstrap for a basic modal showing after a click on a button) and in the modal-body you will find :

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://www.inkwelleditorial.com/pdfSample.pdf" width="500" height="500">this is not working as expected</object>
```

So when I add this code alone (so not inside a bootstrap modal) it's working as expected. It display the pdf in the browser's default pdf viewer. But when I try to implement the pdf inside of the bootstrap modal, nothing seems to appear.

If you have any idea it will really helps me, many hours searching and I've only seen solutions with  tag (which I don't want to use).

Thank you and best regards

Comment: I do see the pdf in modal ... checked with latest Firefox.

Comment: I also see it, and tested in the latest versions of all browsers on Windows (IE, FF, Chrome) except Opera.

Comment: I see it too with FF28 & Chrome34

Answer (score 4):

I have found that bootstrap include a css property that affect to pdf viewing in a modal window.

Change this:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

to:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}
```

If this property is changed everything works properly.

You can see in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/20/

Comment: This is working solution. I tested with object tag on latest Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

**Prevent download manager:**
Again, if you have Internet Download Manager or any other download manager that catches pdf automatically try to prevent it from auto catch pdf link.

Also checkout `PDFObject` JS, it should be interesting

```
<script src="https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject/blob/master/pdfobject.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Please try iframe instead object type pdf

```
<iframe src="http://www.inkwelleditorial.com/pdfSample.pdf" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/9/

Comment: After what I've read about "pdfobject" library, it will not help me. My problem isn't to display the pdf (you can see an updated example : http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/5/ ) that works great if it's included in the body. Problem is only when I try to open a bootstrap modal, it doesn't show the pdf inside of it.

Comment: which browser you are trying? For example I could not view your last example in windows 8 IE App mode either.

Comment: I'm trying on FF 25.0, PDF is displaying well. I know that on some browser it doesn't show well (I must add some conditions for IE but I was just setting a really basic test for found a solution :) ). Displaying the PDF isn't the real problem. The real problem is that it looks like bootstrap put the pdf object behind the modal or something like this (don't really understand why it's not displaying it)

Comment: Solution with the Iframe isn't working and I'm trying to use the object tag specifically (I can't use Iframe for the project). I manage to make it work with jqueryUI dialog ( http://jsfiddle.net/mV6jJ/8/ ) but not working on the same way with bootstrap's modal.

Comment: well, in that case have you tried it on firefox 28 or chrome 34, just in case? because in my end your every example is working except IE App but in desktop version it works though

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution :) It was my browser pdf reader that wasn't configured well. Firefox was using the Adobe Reader for displaying pdf. I replaced that by pdf.js (the pdf reader of Firefox) and now everything seems to work well :) Thank you very much for your time and help :)