# Bootstrap Modal - Save as PDF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf-generation, bootstrap-modal, save-as

I have a bootstrap modal on my website and I would like to extract the Modal body to save it as a PDF. It basically contains a table that is dynamically calculated using javascript and I would like to save this information in a PDF file so that users can download it. What is the best and efficient way to achieve this? Kindly let me know.[image]

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this would be to use an existing library which already takes care of most of the stuff for you. However it all depends on whether you want to do it on the server side or client. If you want to achieve this on server side then I suggest you look into **[iText](http://itextpdf.com/)** and if you want to achieve this on client side then you can look into **[jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)**. I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks and I was looking into jsPDF. I'm sure there should be some free ones out there.

Comment: You're welcome.. jsPDF seems to be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: Also can I have a PDF template in the background and just change the table values from my website when the PDF save button is pressed?

Comment: That's another approach which can be done I don't see why not. You can bind the new values to the pdf on the button pressed event as you mentioned

Comment: Do you have any examples of that?

Comment: I personally don't have an example but **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341781/bootstrap-modal-add-a-object-tag-embedding-a-pdf)** might be of some help