# How to embed an external pdf in a bootstrap modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have an external pdf that I'd like to show embedded in my page. The following works fine:

```
<object frame-resize data="www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="200px" height="200px"></object>
```

Problem: I want to show this embedded pdf in a `modal` window. But as soon as I move it there, the pdf is not displayed correctly anymore:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".my-modal"></div>

            <div class="modal fade my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <object frame-resize data="www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="200px" height="200px"></object>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Result: I'm getting the following error:

```
offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll viewer.js:150:5
scrollIntoView() viewer.js:150
PDFViewer_scrollPageIntoView() viewer.js:4880
pagechange() viewer.js:7394
PDFViewer.prototype.currentPageNumber() viewer.js:4558
pdfViewSetInitialView() viewer.js:6697
resolved()
PDF 0bf9e083c3a94f2cd2e1740080c8c88c [1.4 Acrobat Distiller 7.0.5 (Windows) / Adobe Acrobat 7.0] (PDF.js: 1.1.215)
TypeError: canvas._viewport is undefined
NotFoundError: Node was not found
```

How can I though embed this into a modal dialog?

Interestingly, when I close the modal dialog and open it again, the pdf is rendered correctly!

**Update:**

Solution: I had `css` tag as follows:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This is to prevent content shifting when the webpage exceeds the visible content height.

Question: does anybody know how I can keep this tag, and ignore it just for the modal window?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341781/bootstrap-modal-add-a-object-tag-embedding-a-pdf

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change the transform property of your modal-dialog to none.

```
.modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}
```